# OAuth2: Client Credentials flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth, azure-ad-b2c

Problem: I am currently working on making a REST Api available to clients (the client in this case is not the normal end user who orders the articles, but the client's Web Api that communicates with my system). In order to order different products in my system, each customer may have several accounts for each country separately. Authentication is done by authenticating the client's WebApi application to my system (machine to machine). So it looks like this should be done using OAuth2 Client Credentials Flow based on the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/authentication-flows-app-scenarios#scenarios- and-supported-authentication-flows, but I have doubts about the issue of client accounts for each country separately.

Question: This should be solved by creating a ClientId and ClientSecret for each client account per country separately or, however, one client account should be created, while the country should be sent by the client in each request to the Api or before adding the country as a scope or claim to access token.
Additionally, I am not sure if Client Credentials Flow is a good choice in this situation, so I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: As soon as you do not want to correlate the activity of one client vs another client, they should have their own client_id/secret pair.

Answer (score 0):

**CLIENTS**

Ideally each client company should have a single client credential for getting access tokens. In sone cases, such as when there are different legal subdivisions, this can be extended. By default use a single value, but you need to understand your clients.

A client credentials flow between companies can involve stronger credentials if needed, such as JWT client assertions or Mutual TLS - as in [this advanced tutorial](https://curity.io/resources/learn/mutual-tls-api/).

**CLAIMS**

In your system you should map domain specific data needed for authorization against each client ID. This might include country specific access to products or whatever makes sense for your scenario.

This data can then be either included in access tokens at the time of issuance, or looked up when an access token is first received, then cached for subsequent requests with the same token. Step 3 of my [Authorization Blog Post](https://authguidance.com/2017/10/03/api-tokens-claims/) explains a couple of design patterns here.

**API REQUESTS**

How the client gets data in API requests is interesting:

- Is data for all countries owned by the caller? If so let them select the data they want via a country parameter during API requests.
- If the API client shoild never be able to see data for a country, that suggests that in at least some cases you need different clients per country.

**SUMMARY**

Define clients in terms of what makes sense for those companies. Avoid an explosion of clients in order to manage access rights for the same data owner. Exact solutions depend on your domain specific requirements. OAuth is a framework that is meant to be adapted.

Answer (score 0):

If your entire existing data-model silos 'countries' by a concept of an account, then a set of credentials per account might be the easiest.

But it sounds to me that your data-model doesn't fully capture your actual business well. It sounds to me like you have a concept of a 'customer/client' that has access to one of more 'accounts', each representing a country.

So a more correct way to model this might be to structure your API so that a single API client can access all of the related accounts, and your API should perhaps be structured so that the idea of an `accountId` is somehow passed (usually in the URL for REST apis). For example, each API endpoint can be prefixed with `/account/123`.

To me this is more of a data-modelling and API architecture question than anything OAuth2-specific.